# Add sequence before base sequence

Tags: xml, xsd

I have this XML:

```
<Base>
  <ElementInBase />
  <OtherElementInBase />
</Base>

<Derived>
  <ElementInChildren />
  <ElementInBase />
  <OtherElementInBase />
</Derived>
```

So basically i want to allow another sequence in `Derived` to be appear before the sequence from parent `Base`.

Currently i have this schema:

```
<xs:complexType name="Base">
    <xs:sequence >
        <xs:element ref="ElementInBase"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
        <xs:element ref="OtherElementInBase "  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Derived">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="Base">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="ElementInChildren"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>

    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>
```

But this only allows `ElementInChildren` to be after elements from `Base`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to define your `Base` as an **element group** and reference to it in your `Derived` complexType:

```
<xs:group name="Base">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="ElementInBase"  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
      <xs:element ref="OtherElementInBase "  minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:complexType name="Derived">
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="ElementInChildren" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1"></xs:element>
    <xs:group ref="Base"/>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

That will place the `ElementInChildren` before the content defined in `Base`.

Read also my answer here: [In XML Schema, why does an element group tag even exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26273452)